# How to calculate the count of different strings individual in JSON data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON data which has to calculate the count of the type in the JSON data based on data. So by using ajax or jquery, we need to perform this task.

```
var item = [{name:a,type:abc},{name:a,type:abc},{name:a,type:abc},{name:a,type:abc},{name:a,type:abc},{name:a,type:ac},{name:a,type:bc},{name:a,type:ac},{name:a,type:ab},{name:a,type:ac}]
```

The code should be applicable even if the data is changed.

Comment: It's unclear what you are wanting to count, and by what criteria they are considered "different".

Answer (score 3):

You can count the various types by using `reduce()` to create an object keyed to `type`. Increment it if it exists or set it to one if it is the first time seeing it in the loop:

```js
var item = [{name:'a',type:'abc'},{name:'a',type:'abc'},{name:'a',type:'abc'},{name:'a',type:'ac'},{name:'a',type:'ab'},{name:'a',type:'ac'},{name:'a',type:'ab'},{name:'a',type:'ac'}, {name:'a',type:'xx'}]

let counts = item.reduce((counts, {type}) => {
    counts[type] = counts[type] ? counts[type] + 1 : 1
    return counts
}, {})
console.log(counts)
```